# Floating label on top inputs

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to float a label on top of the input but it's not working correctly? Maybe I messed up the CSS? Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Heres what it looks like at the moment:
http://prntscr.com/37hw30

HTML:

```
<form id="loginformitem" name="loginformitem" method="post" style="float:right">

    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="log_username" class="logintext"  id="username" placeholder="Username" style="margin-left:100px">

        <label for="password">Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="log_password" class="logintext" id="password" placeholder="Password">

         <button type="submit" class="loginbutton" name="login" >Login now</button>

     </form>
```

CSS:

```
.logintext {
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 2px 2px 3px 2px;
font-size: 13px;
color: #222;
}

form label {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #a4c0d7;
}
```

Comment: Add `float: left; clear: left;` to both input and label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrap `label` & `input` into a `<p>` or a `<span>` displayed as `inline-block`.

`input` can be displayed as `block` to break the line.

HTML

```
<form id="loginformitem" name="loginformitem" method="post" >
  <span>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="log_username" class="logintext"  id="username" placeholder="Username" >
  </span>
  <span>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="log_password" class="logintext" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </span>
  <button type="submit" class="loginbutton" name="login" >Login now</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
form span {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 50px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
span input {
 display:block;/* if you want submit under , do form input {} to include it too */
}
form {
  float:right;
  /* for the demo */
  border:solid;
  border-radius:1em;
  padding:0.25em;
}
```

Turns to look like **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xpm5P/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#loginformitem input , #loginformitem label {
clear : left ,
float : left
}
```